# How to update time in MySQL, opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am trying to take insert hours and minutes from MySQL in OpenCart

when I am trying to run a normal query in MySQL its running fine

```
UPDATE `oc_delivery_time` SET `delivery_time_name`="Slot2",`delivery_time_from`=TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "9:30 AM", "%h:%i %p" ) ),`delivery_time_to`=TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "12:00 PM", "%h:%i %p" ) ),`status`="1" WHERE `delivery_time_id`="2"
```

**but when i do it in opencart I am getting this error.**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gdr\admin\model\localisation\delivery_time.php
```

**here is my query in opencart model**

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "delivery_time SET delivery_time_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_name']) . "', delivery_time_from = 'TIME( STR_TO_DATE( " . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_from']) . ", "%h:%i %p" ) )', delivery_time_to = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_to']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "' WHERE delivery_time_id = '" . (int)$delivery_time_id . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "delivery_time SET delivery_time_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_name']) . "', delivery_time_from = 'TIME( STR_TO_DATE( " . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_from']) . ", \"%h:%i %p\" ) )', delivery_time_to = '" . $this->db->escape($data['delivery_time_to']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "' WHERE delivery_time_id = '" . (int)$delivery_time_id . "'");
```